# How to proxy SaltStack behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, centos6, saltstack

By default, when installed, Saltstack uses port 4505 and 4506 to connect with Minions.

But I can't open port 4505 and 4506 on Salt master server. Is there any way we can configure Salt master behind Nginx and have minions to connect master through Nginx.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the master ports through the configuration file to some ports you are able to open. That way you don't need a proxy at all.

So these are the steps:

1. In your master's configuration file set the [publish
   port](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#publish-port)
   and the [ret
   port](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#ret-port)
   to the desired ones and reload the master;
2. In you minion's configuration file set the [master
   port](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#master-port)
   to the same port one you  set as ret_port in your master